# Boot order of programs

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, boot-issues

I have a Pi running basic Wheezy, which functions, among other things, as a web server. I have it hooked up to run Tiny-Tiny-RSS (though for the purposes here, it could be any PHP app) over PostgreSQL.

Usually, I run the Pi headless, so I don't see the startup log, but lately I hooked it up to a screen, so I saw something startling - PHP was outputting warnings of not being able to connect to the database because, unsurprisingly, it wasn't up. And indeed, after a bit of research, an ls of /etc/rc2.d/ (and checking that this was indeed the correct runlevel) showed me that postgresql was prefixed with S03 and php5-fpm was prefixed with S01. I then alter the LSB header of php5-fpm to have the line `#Required Start: postgresql`. No dice, a reboot shows the same startup order and the same warning, which is output BEFORE the postgresql service writes that it's starting. In despair, I manually change the link order so postgresql is prefixed with S01 and php5-fpm is prefixed with S02.

Again, no dice, which leads me to believe I am missing something incredibly basic. What can I do to make sure the php service does not load before the postgresql service?

Answer (score 1):

In order to update the rc2.d links you need to run update-rc.d

```
update-rc.d php5-fpm defaults
```

Comment: This sounded ideal, but the error still occurs.

Comment: Strange when I test it, it changes the Sxx according to required services. Perhaps you can try `update-rc.d -f php5-fpm remove` and next `update-rc.d  php5-fpm default` ? Otherwise could you precise what occurs in the rc2.d links ?